# Validating a sequence of points as a convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm familiar with the classical convex hull calculation algorithms. The lower bound for computing the CH of a set of points $P$ is $n\log(n)$.

However, what if I'm given a sequence of points and told they form a CH? One check is to "walk the points" in order and check for "left turns" (CCW). However, this doesn't handle the case of self-intersections (you could imagine a counter-example that "winds around starting from the center" making only CCW turns.

I've been told this "validation" can be done in $O(n)$ time, but to check for self-intersection naively, I see $O(n^2)$ time.

My next thought is to run [Graham's Scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan). Since the points are presumably on a CH, it takes $O(n)$ to find the lower left point, say $p_0$, and from there, **I THINK you can guarantee** that all points $p_1, p_2,\dots,p_n$ are already sorted by angle between $p_0$ and $x$-axis. As you move the three-point-window forward along the hull, the points ahead are still properly sorted. The reasoning for $O(n)$ then follows per normal reasoning for Graham's scan, minus the need for $O(n\log n)$ sorting.

1) Is my assumption, in bold, correct? 
2) Is there an easier method that wouldn't involve running Graham's scan?

Comment: how is $P$ given to you? if it can be given in arbitrary order, then the assumption in bold can clearly fail.

Comment: This is a first-week homework exercise in any computational geometry course.  Hint: Winding number.

Comment: Do we know this problem is insoluble in linear time if the points are given in arbitrary order?

Comment: @SashoNikolov - Maybe it wasn't clear enough in the O.P. - A sequence of points that is supposed to be a traversal of the CH - so essentially, we're trying to validate if the given sequence, not set, is a convex hull.

Comment: @JeffE - This is not a HW question, nor is it for a computational geometry class. But thanks for the backhanded comment. The winding number is interesting, but it seems like finding a position within the sequence of points to form the ray, and choosing a direction, would not guarantee that multiple edges would be crossed in a self-intersecting sequence. I'm not sure if WN is the correct solution for this problem.

Comment: @Jmoney38 If the points are a convex hull, then they're star-shaped with respect to any point in their interior, so any point there will do; in particular, the mean of the points will work perfectly fine for computing the winding number.  And you misunderstand what winding number he's referring to - you're computing, in essence, the total angle subtended by the sequence as it passes all the way around and making certain that it is 2π.

Comment: (If your chosen inner point is inside the 'outer loop' of a doubly-wound hull but not the inner loop then you may still compute a winding number of 1, but in that case your 'walk around the loop' will require you going backwards, which couldn't happen for a proper convex hull.  The winding number test isn't enough by itself, but winding number + turning test works.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is easier than you think. As you remarked you should check if you take always CCW or CW turns. But of course, this might result in a curve that is self-intersecting. But you can detect this easily, just sum up then angles of the "turns". Since your curve is closed this angle sum is a multiple of $2\pi$. If it *winds up* exactly once it does not self-intersect. In this case the angle sum is $2\pi$. Thus you are left with checking, if the angles sum up to $2\pi$.

See [this paper](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/c/h/checking_geometric_programs_or_verificat_700015.pdf) for analogues in higher dimension.

Interestingly, in the smooth version (CCW turn is here positive sectional curvature), for a 1d curve you still have to check the winding number, but by an old [theorem of Hadamard](http://portail.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1897_5_3_A12_0.pdf),  if higher dimensional (immersed) manifolds have positive sectional curvature everywhere, then they enclose a *convex* body.